# How to Write a Flutter Ternary Operator with one of the conditions being null (do nothing)

Tags: flutter, dart

The following works in Flutter, however, I have an IDE warning to avoid "unnecessary statements." I'm sure many will pipe in citing the Latin root of three in ternary and other critiques, and I appreciate that kind of fun dialog, I really do, however, **sometimes in a nested sequence, this stuff comes up..not just in the simple example I'm giving**.

As I said, the below works, I just get an Android Studio IDE warning. I'd probably be better off to correct it if there is something more appropriate when using a ternary operator

```
x == 4 ? doSomething() : null
```

Couldn't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio at least has updated this check and it is now allowed without warnings. It was a common logic in validators at least, and someone saw the light.  So the correct answer was: It's perfectly reasonable and good code.  (at least in my opinion!)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use ternary.

```
if( x == 4 ) doSomething()
```

Applies to `List` and `Map` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is not built for such a situation. It should use where we have at least two options

```
condition ? doThisIfTrue() : doThisIfFalse()
```

If we have only one option, then simply use **if**

```
if ( condition ) {
   doThis
}
```

The code that you wrote, is not wrong either, but that is not use of ternary operator.